# Can ggplot draw an outline around each legend entry?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R how do I get ggplot to draw an outline around each legend point? The NA legend entry below looks like "nothing", for lack of a border around said point.

```
miss <- factor(sample(c(NA, 1:5), nrow(mtcars), replace = TRUE))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = miss)) +
  scale_color_grey(na.value = "white") + 
  geom_point(shape = 1, color = "black") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: legend without border outlines]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. You can consider as an option using `shape=21` and enable `fill` option:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
miss <- factor(sample(c(NA, 1:5), nrow(mtcars), replace = TRUE))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(shape=21,aes(fill = miss),color='black') +
  scale_fill_grey(na.value = "white") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]